# I keep getting Expected "`onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type." error and i dont know how to fix it

Tags: javascript

```
import React from 'react';
import useState from './App';
import username from './App';
import setUsername from './App';
import setAppState from './App';

function LoginPage(props) {

 const onClick = () => {
    props.onLogin(setUsername);

  }

  return (
    <div className="chat-login-page-container">
     <div className="chat-login-page-controls-container">
       <h4>Set your username</h4>
        <input type="text" 
               placeholder="Username"
               value={props.username} 
               username={username}
               setUsername={username}
           
               onChange={props.onChange} />
           
        <button type="button" disabled={username.length === 0} onClick='onClick'>Log 
 in</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

I keep trying to fix the code with diffrent variables and trying to make it not a value and it just dosnt work. Im at a loss and dont know what to do.

Comment: JavaScript in `onclick` attributes are evaluated in the global scope. `onClick` is local to `LoginPage`.

Answer (score 1):

1. First, you should use object destructuring for props

   const {username, onChange, onLogin} = props;
2. In component "button", the property `"onClick"` expects a function. With your code `onClick='onClick'`, the property is getting a **string** and not a function. I'm not sure what the onClick function should do, but it should look somehow like this:

```
<button type="button" disabled={username.length === 0} onClick={()=>{onLogin(setUsername}}>Log in</button>
```